# Broken sort after search

Tags: android, sorting, actionbarsherlock

I wrote a simply app with ListView and ActionBarSharlock (ABS). I have my objects, custom ArrayAdapter, in my ABS I have SearchView and drop down list, now about my problem, if I'm searching something before sort all works fine, but after "search" a sort function is broken.

```
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId) {
                        switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            countryArrayAdapter.sort(new SortByAZ());
                            break;
                        case 1:

...................


        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                countryArrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I do wrong?

Nothing. The problem is `ArrayAdapter` is buggy.

Relevant code from API 17 implementation of `ArrayAdapter`:

```
public void sort(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        if (mOriginalValues != null) {
            Collections.sort(mOriginalValues, comparator);
        } else {
            Collections.sort(mObjects, comparator);
        }
    }
    if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public T getItem(int position) {
    return mObjects.get(position);
}
```

As you can see, it sometimes sorts different list. Actually after you first filter it, `mOriginalValues` becomes not null.

There is a workaround for it. You have to filter it again with the same text value after every change (sort, insert, etc.) to the list.

I always suggest not to use `ArrayAdapter` and instead build on `BaseAdapter` with your own `Filter` implementation when needed.

**Edit:**

Just found this is a known issue for a few years already: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9666